# Visual Basic (VB) Forms: wait for a user click?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm making a simple form that is to step through a program iteratively.

How can I get it to run a method each time a user clicks a button and wait once it is finished for the next click?

Comment: You may want to focus on the version of VB you're actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question very well, but is it like the "Next" button on a Wizard?
You can have a State variable to store the current "state", so at starup its has the value 1. when click "Next" then do the code for State=1 and then change to State=2 and so on.

Inside you Click event you can have a case statement to proceed according

Comment: Good point... I wasn't clear on the request either, but your suggestion of a state machine pattern makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a method that gets called when it sees the `OnClick` event.

The simplest way to do this is to double-click the button in the GUI Form Designer, and it will go to the code page and start the method for you with the correct syntax.